# how to load Video from ipad library in ipad app

Tags: ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an iPad app in which when I click on the button it opens a popover with the iPad library to see the photos and pics. I want that when I click the button it should also show video in that but it does not show videos.

In device when I see library it shows videos but when popover opens in app it does not show any video.

```
UIImagePickerController *pckrImage = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pckrImage.delegate = self;
if (isiPhone) {
  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])   {
     pckrImage.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
     [self presentModalViewController:pckrImage animated:YES];
  }
}
else {
  popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:pckrImage];
  [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(450.0f, 825.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Create normal popover then add this code to for button 'choose photo from gallery'

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker1.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(300, 200);
imagePicker1.delegate = self;
imagePicker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

Popcontroller = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker1];
[Popcontroller presentPopoverFromRect:cell1.ButtonAddPicture.frame
                               inView:cell1.ButtonAddPicture.superview
             permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                             animated:YES];
```

and for video add following line to above code

```
imagePicker1.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
```